# CSS photo gallery tweaking help

Tags: css, image, xhtml, html, resize

I've been trying the CSS photo gallery example [here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/gallery.html) to set up my own ([here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/s2h5z/)). Everything works fine except:

(1) The divs are setup using absolute measures in px. I find it frustrating to have to resize and adapt my photos to fit them. Instead, is there a way to setup up all the dimensions of the gallery (via the CSS), such as in % or em, so that the gallery adapts to the images I put in it, and also dynamically fit the viewport size of a browser?

(2) I tried to add my own photos to the gallery, yet if my photos' dimensions don't match that of the divs, they overflow. Is there a way to specify larger images to change their sizes to fill their containers, and maintain their aspect ratio?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS photo gallery tweaking help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057328/css-photo-gallery-tweaking-help)

Comment: @Kyle: This looks like a back button edit.  I closed the original since this one contains a link to example code.

Comment: Oops, didn't realise the question appears twice. Thanks for the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) I would not set up the entire gallery in % or scale it dynamically to fit the browser. This can lead to unexpected results and problems. To fit the images into the divs you could set up a bash script with imagemagick to resize all your images. (May even your server can do this for you. If you are on Windows there are programs to batch-resize images like [Shrink-O-Matic](http://toki-woki.net/p/Shrink-O-Matic/).)

(2) You can just set up a fixed hight or width (only one of them) to put the image in a fixed dimension. The browser will then scale the image to fit that value proportionally. The CSS would look like this:

```
#container .pics span img {height: 400px;}
```

That should work.

If you really want a gallery that "scales" to the browser size, may you have to look around for another one. There are thousands out there and it would be to much work to modify this one to your needs.

Good luck.